# Why do we need file .gitignore.save?

Tags: git

After changes in file `.gitignore` I noticed in my iOS repository two new files `.gitignore.save` and `.gitignore.save.1`. Actually in `.gitignore.save` I see old data of `.gitignore` file and in `.gitignore.save.1` I see actual data of `.gitignore` file.
Please explain why these files are needed?

Comment: Seems like "garbage" files, temp files used while editing that should have been deletetd. Look for `".save" file"` in a Search Engine, you should see results.

Comment: They are not needed by git. It looks like your text editor left copies for you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with iOS or Swift.